# How to paste text with syntax highlighting from the IDE (in format HTML) under Linux in MS Office format?

Tags: linux, excel, ide, clipboard, wine

Good afternoon. It so happened that for several years I have kept notes on programming in large Excel files with through the table of contents. All code is illuminated to every part of the code you can instantly get there thanks to hyperlinks within the document. Everything was fine until after I moved to Ubuntu by working necessity. In linux there are several options - Libre Office, Open Office and work with MS Office under Wine.

While none of these options could not solve the underlying problem.

When you copy data from the IDE PhpStorm captured lighting, it is very important to quickly understand code. So - when you insert data in Libre Office everything is inserted into a single cell and read a large piece of code more than one screen becomes impossible. Either one line - but without syntax highlighting.

Today I installed Wine, PlayOnLinux, MS Office 2010, everything seems nice and cool - but when copying data from the clipboard into the linux Vine insertion error occurs. The data can only be inserted in the format of a naked text without highlighting.

If anyone knows how to solve my problem - I shall be grateful for your help.

Maybe there are some other alternatives Excel to store large, complex synopses?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I recall Libreoffice will read the excel file without changing anything, just tell libreoffice to open the excel file.
If libreoffice doesn't recognise the xls suffix, use "open with".
You can always tell libreoffice to save the xls file as a libreoffice spreadsheet later, as I imagine that Phpstorm simply uses the same method to decide what to use to open a file as everything else.
If some reason you are still having trouble, investigate `unoconv` which is available in the repositories.